# What Latex font is this (letters look narrower and wider-spaced)? (PDF given)

Tags: fonts

I have tried all of the methods suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture) but none of them worked (returned none or empty font names). Can someone identify the font used in this document? Is there any package for this? It looks somewhat different from what you get in Latex by default. The letters seem to be narrower and more spaced.

[image]

Full document:
https://windsim.com/Windsimarchive/library%20--%20papers-presentations/proceeding.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. From your image it is computer modern font. It is default in LaTeX. However from the properties of the Adobe Reader document you can see the fonts used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm on Linux and already tried strings and pdffonts commands. Neither worked. I'll check Adobe Reader as soon as I'm on a Windows PC.

Comment: You're welcome. I am sure that is Computer Modern font: it is the canonical font of LaTeX/TeX. I have seen that it is an old file from 1998, and a long time ago .pdf output was dependent on which . pdf reader was used. So you will see a suboptimal appearance.